# C++ Prime Numbers program

Tags: c++, primes

I'm working on a C++ program that determines and prints the prime numbers between 3 and an integer 'x' the user inputs.  I'm assuming that I need a double nested loop for this, one to iterate from 3 to x and the other to check if the number is prime.  I think it needs to do something like go from 2 to x-1?  I'm just really not sure how to do this syntax-wise. Thanks for any help! :)

EDIT:
 This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main(){

   int x;
   int i;
   int j;

   cout << "Please enter an integer 'x' greater than 3: " << endl;

   cin >> x;

   if (x <= 3){

        cout << "Please enter new value 'x' greater than 3: " << endl;

        cin >> x;
   }
        for(int i=3; i<=x; i++){
                for(j=2; j<i; j++){
                   if(i%j == 0)
                        break;
                   else if(i == j+1);
                        cout << i << endl;
                   }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

And I when I enter 10 as 'x' I get the output:
3
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
9

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: You should check out the Sieve of Erastothenes.

Comment: You are on the right track, I think, but your question is not really well-formed. It would be more appropriate if it asked a very specific question like: what is the syntax for a loop in C++, or do I need nested loops to compute primes from 1 to N or something.  Also, there are many examples showing how to do this already posted in various places, easily accessible, so you might want to do just a bit of research and ask again if you're still confused.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched for other questions here that relate to the same topic?

Comment: minimal edit to fix your code: http://hpaste.org/81471 . Consider posting such questions on http://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1):

Provided your `X` is small enough, you can use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to do it more efficiently. This is ideal for the "primes up to X" case since it maintains a memory of previously discarded primes. It does so by keeping a set of flags for each candidate number, all initially set to true (except for 1, of course).

Then you take the first true value (2), output that as a prime, and then set the flags for all multiples of that to false.

Then carry on with:

- 3;
- 5 (since 4 was a multiple of 2);
- 7 (since 6 was a multiple of 2 and 3);
- 11 (since 8 and 10 were multiples of 2 and 9 was a multiple of 3);
- 13 (since 12 was a multiple of 2);
- 17 (since 14 and 16 were multiples of 2 and 15 was a multiple of 3 and 5);
- and so on.

Pseudo-code would be similar to:

```
def showPrimesUpTo (num):
    // create array of all true values

    array isPrime[2..num] = true

    // start with 2 and go until finished

    currNum = 2
    while currNum <= num:
        // if prime, output it

        if isPrime[currNum]:
            output currNum

            // also flag all multiples as nonprime

            clearNum = currNum * 2
            while clearNum <= num:
                isprime[clearNum] = false
                clearNum = clearNum + currNum

        // advance to next candidate

        currNum = currNum + 1
```

Otherwise, you can do trial division as per your suggestion. The basic idea is to check each number from 2 up to the square root of your target number to see if it's a multiple. In pseudo-code, that would be something like:

```
def isPrime (num):
    // val is the value to check for factor

    val = 2

    // only need to check so far

    while val * val <= num:
        // check if an exact multiple

        if int (num / val) * val == num:
            return false

        // no, carry on

        val = val + 1

    // if no factors found, it is a prime

    return true
```

The reason you only need to check up to the square root is because, if you find a factor above there, you would have already found the corresponding factor *below* the square root.

For example, `3 x 17` is `51`. If you're checking the numbers from 2 through 50 to see if `51` is prime, you'll find `3` first, meaning you never need to check `17`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main (char argv) 
{
    int tempNum = atoi(argv);
    for (int i=3; i<=tempNum; i++) 
        for (int j=2; j*j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0) 
                break;
            else if (j+1 > sqrt(i)) {
                cout << i << " ";

            }

        }   

    return 0;
}
```

[Printing prime numbers from 1 through 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200879/printing-prime-numbers-from-1-through-100)
Basically this, but modified

Comment: you check the `j+1 > sqrt(i)` test for each `j <= sqrt(i)` but it can succeed only once, for the very last one. Plus, what you really mean is whether you exited the loop due to `break` or not. So better make _that_ apparent in your code. :) You can do this with an additional *flag* variable, or a `GOTO`, like e.g. [this here](http://hpaste.org/81475).

Answer (score 0):

I find this one pretty fast and efficient

```
 int main(){
    for(int i=3; i<=X; i++)    
            if(IsPrime(i)){
               cout<<i<<endl;
            }
    }

 bool IsPrime(int num){
    /* use commented part if want from 2
        if(num<=1)

            return false;

        if(num==2)

            return true;
    */
        if(num%2==0)

            return false;

        int sRoot = sqrt(num*1.0);

        for(int i=3; i<=sRoot; i+=2)

        {

            if(num%i==0)

                return false;

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Well then you must only be doing small primes.

Comment: @LokiAstari didn't get you? In what reference? If there is any flaw with above code?  please suggest.

Comment: This is not efficient: Its O(n^2), thus only useful for small primes. There are several good optimizations on-top of this technique that make it much more efficient. But really you want `Sieve of Eratosthenes`.

Comment: @LokiAstari thanks alot .. will definitely look for that

Comment: while searching for `Sieve of Eratosthenes` got to know that `sieve of Atkins` faster than `Sieve of Eratosthenes`