# Errors in Prime Numbers Program (C++)

Tags: c++, primes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Prime Numbers program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574823/c-prime-numbers-program)

I am working on a c++ program to calculate all prime numbers between 3 and an integer 'x'. 
When I enter 10 as 'x' I am getting the output:
3
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
9

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main(){

   int x;
   int i;
   int j;

   cout << "Please enter an integer 'x' greater than 3: " << endl;

   cin >> x;

   if (x <= 3){

        cout << "Please enter new value 'x' greater than 3: " << endl;

        cin >> x;
   }
        for(int i=3; i<=x; i++){
                for(j=2; j<i; j++){
                   if(i%j == 0)
                        break;
                   else if(i == j+1);
                        cout << i << endl;
                   }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, the old semi-colon on if-statement thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offending line:

```
else if(i == j+1);
```

Remove the semi-colon.

Comment: This made it work perfectly, thank you very much! :)

Comment: No worries.  For an extra challenge, you should try implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes as suggested by Arun Saha.  I did a little experiment with it a couple of days ago, and found it took less than 200 milliseconds to calculate primes up to 15 million.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Good suggestion, but I would recommend mastering the basics first.

Comment: +1 for the most optimal (based on time complexity) solution provided..