# Printing out Prime Numbers from 2 to 1000

Tags: java, methods, primes

I am writing a code that write all the prime numbers from 2 to 1000 in a file, named primes.txt. For some reason I am not able to figure out the correct way to do this problem.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Problem6 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter prw = new PrintWriter("primes.txt");
        for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++){
            if (checkIfPrime(i) == true){
                System.out.println(i);
                prw.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkIfPrime (int num){
        boolean isPrime = true;  
        for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++){
            if ( num % i == 0 ){
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }

        return isPrime;
    }
}
```

I just dont know what to do... Please help Thanks!

Comment: Please state the *precise* issue you are running into.

Comment: By correct way, do you mean an efficient way?

Answer (score 6):

What happens when you pass in your first number, `2`, to `checkIfPrime`?  It will take remainder of 2 divided by 2, which is 0, falsely claiming that `2` is not prime.

You need to stop testing remainders before you actually get to `num`.  Stop your `i` for loop before `i` gets to `num`.  (In fact, you can stop after `i` has reached the square root of `num`).

```
for (int i = 2; i < num; i++){
```

or even

```
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++){
```

If you're feeling adventurous, you may try implementing the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), which marks all composite numbers up to an arbitrary limit (in this question, 1000).  Then you just print out the rest of the numbers -- the primes.

Comment: +1 for sqrt variant. It is good to notice that result of dividing `num` by divisor smaller that sqrt will be divisor larger than sqrt, but since we already checked smaller divisors there is no need to checki greater ones.

Comment: The last example isn't entirely trustworthy.  It should be OK for `num` in the range 1 to 1000.  But suppose we want to deal with large numbers and `num` is a perfect square, `q*q`, that is close to the maximum for a `long`, which is 2^63-1.  `Math.sqrt` takes a `double`, which has only 52 mantissa bits, so some precision will be lost.  In theory, this means that `Math.sqrt(num)` could be slightly less than `q`, and the comparison as written could fail when `i==q`, which would be incorrect.  In practice, I couldn't get this to happen.  But one does need to be careful with floats.

Comment: P.S. that's why I prefer `for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++)` even though it's a bit less readable.  Integer arithmetic is exact, so I try to avoid floating-point arithmetic when it isn't needed.

Comment: @ajb Your loop will only work for `i < 65536`, because the multiplication will overflow. You need to make sure that one of the multiplicands is a long, for example `1L * i * i`. Or declare `i` as `long` for simplicity.

Comment: @starblue Sloppy on my part.  If `num` is an `int`, though, my code will work fine because `i` can never be > 46341.  If `num` is `long`, `i` definitely must also be `long`.  But yes, if you use an expression like this in a `for` condition, you have to be really careful about boundary conditions.  If this were C++ and `num` were an `unsigned int` then my code could fail.

Answer (score 3):

calculation can be made even faster by checking the division with prime numbers only. Any non prime number is divisible by some prime number smaller than itself.

```
    static List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 2; i < 10000; i++) {
        if(checkPrime(i)){
            primes.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(primes);
}

private static boolean checkPrime(int n) {
    for (Integer i : primes) {
        if(i*i > n ){
            break;
        }else if(n%i==0 )
            return false;
     }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: actually breaking from the `for` loop when `i*i <= n` is no longer true should make this code (it works to 10,000) run about 30 times faster (excluding the printing). You can break your `if` in two.

Comment: Thanks @Ness. Updated the code as per your comment. I have not measured the performance. My gut feeling is that as you increase n it will show better performance.

Comment: you're welcome. for me, it's more readable this way: `if(i*i > n) { break; } else if(n%i==0) { return false; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `for` condition in `checkIfPrime(int num)` to

```
for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
```

---

BTW `if (checkIfPrime(i) == true){` can be written as `if (checkIfPrime(i)){`

Answer (score 1):

A number `num` is prime if it's not divisible by any other number that is greater than one **and smaller than `num`**.  Where is this in your code?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could "hard-code" an *[incremental sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Incremental_sieve) on a [2-3-5-7 wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization)* to print the primes up to *1000*. In [C-like pseudocode](http://ideone.com/fRQsOz),

```
primes_1000()
{
   // the 2-3-5-7 wheel
   int wh[48] = {10,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,
                  2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2};
   // core primes' multiples, each with its pointer into the wheel
   int m[7][4] = { {1,11,11,11*11}, {2,13,13,13*13}, {3,17,17,17*17},
                   {4,19,19,19*19}, {5,23,23,23*23}, {6,29,29,29*29},
                   {7,31,31,31*31} };    // 23*23 = 529 
   int i=1, p=11, k=0;
   print(2); print(3); print(5); print(7);
   p = 11;             // first number on the wheel - the first candidate
   do {
      // the smallest duplicate multiple is 121*13, ==> no dups below 1000!
      for( k=0; k < 7; ++k) {
         if ( p == m[k][3] ) {             // p is a multiple of m[k][1] prime:
            m[k][2] += wh[ m[k][0]++ ];    //   next number on the wheel
            m[k][3]  = m[k][1] * m[k][2];  //   next multiple of m[k][1] 
            m[k][0] %= 48;                 //   index into the wheel
            break;
         }
      }
      if (k == 7) {    // multiple of no prime below 32 -
          print(p);    //   - a prime below 1000!   (32^2 = 1024)
      }
      p += wh[i++];    // next number on the candidates wheel
      i %= 48;         // wrap around to simulate circular list
   } while ( p < 1000 );
}
```

For primes below *500*, only 4 sieve variables need to be maintained, for the additional core primes *{11,13,17,19}* above the  wheel's inherent primes *2,3,5,7*.

(see also [Printing prime numbers from 1 through 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200879/printing-prime-numbers-from-1-through-100/12543821#12543821)).

`m` is the dictionary of base primes and their multiples on the wheel (`multiplesOf(p) = map( multiplyBy(p), rollWheelFrom(p) )`, each with its own index into the wheel. It should really be a priority queue, min-ordered by the multiples' values.

For a true unbounded solution [a separate primes supply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621/849891) can be maintained, to extend the dictionary prime by prime when the next prime's square is reached among the candidates.