# How to factorize a number?

Tags: c, math

I've been asked to factorize a number and show it in a specific way .

e.g: 100 = 2^2*5^2

This is the C++ code I've used so far with no dice , unfortunately:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

//IsPrime indicates whether a given number is or is not prime.
bool IsPrime(long long n)
{   
    int j = 3;
    if (n == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = 3; j <= sqrt(n); j += 2)
        {
            if (n%j == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    long long n_orig,n, i=3 , primecount=0;
    scanf("%lld", &n_orig);
    n = n_orig;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        printf("1");
        return 0;
    }
    if (IsPrime(n))
    {
        printf("%lld", n);
        return 0;
    }
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        while (n >= 2 && n % 2 == 0)
        {
            primecount++;
            n = n / 2;
        }
        if (primecount == 1)
        {
            printf("2*");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("2^%lld*", primecount);
        }
    }
    primecount = 0;
    n = n_orig;
    while (i <= n/2)
    {
        if (IsPrime(i))
        {
            while (n >= i && n % i == 0)
            {
                primecount++;
                n = n / i;
            }
        }
        n = n_orig;
        if (primecount == 0)
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if (primecount == 1)
        {
            printf("%lld*", i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%lld^%lld*", i, primecount);
        }
        primecount = 0;
        i+=2;
    }
    printf("\b");
    return 0;
}
```

Using this code I was able to generate a few test cases, though when I uploaded my answer to the website where the codes are presumably evaluated , out of 7 test cases (which I cannot know what they exactly are) , *I pass 3* , **fail 3** and *exceed time limit (the one that hasn't even been declared in the question) in one case*. I'd really appreciate some help , and please be noob-friendly!

Also , I don't really wanna know if my answer could be improved in some way , **my top priority right now is understanding why MY own code doesn't work as intended.**

P.S : Usage of *iostream* and *array*s is not allowed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger during execution?

Comment: Is 1 a prime? Is 0 a prime?

Comment: How often do you call the sqrt function?

Comment: @CoryKramer I have actually but of course for relatively small numbers , since it can take quite while tracing it for big integers. And surprisingly enough , I haven't encountered an issue yet.

Comment: @gnasher729 Well 1 and 0 are definitely not primes. And also , I've used the sqrt function just once , in the IsPrime function I've myself have created.

Comment: Wrong, you are not using the sqrt function "just once". The `sqrt()` function gets called ***on every iteration of the loop***. You cannot rely on the C++ compiler optimizing it out. Every time the loop iterates, the loop condition is checked, and the loop expression gets evaluated. That's how C++ works.

Comment: Use `j*j <= n` instead of `j <= sqrt(n)`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ahhh , I see ,so any reason why I'm getting "Wrong" instead of "Time Limit Exceeded" ?

Comment: @SauravSahu Much obliged! Though I'm still getting the same results

Comment: What is max value for n ?

Comment: I think you can hardcode prime numbers up to let's say 1000 into an array and calculate bigger if necessary using it. That could speed up your code significantly

Comment: the question talks about a C++ code, but the posted code is C.  Please clarify

Comment: with `C` code, need to have the statement: `#include <stdbool.h>`  for the definition of `bool` etc.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned long long PrintMultiplicity(unsigned long long n,unsigned long long factor)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;

    while (n%factor == 0)
    {
        count++;
        n /= factor;
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        printf("%llu^%u",factor,count);
        if (n > 1)
            printf("*");
    }

    return n;
}

void PrintFactorization(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long factor;
    unsigned int add;

    printf("%llu = ",n);

    n = PrintMultiplicity(n,2);
    n = PrintMultiplicity(n,3);

    // Check only factors that are adjacent to multiples of 6
    for (factor = 5, add = 2; factor <= sqrt(n); factor += add, add = 6-add)
        n = PrintMultiplicity(n,factor);

    if (n > 1)
        printf("%llu^1",n);

    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long n;
    scanf("%llu",&n);
    PrintFactorization(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This one seems to be working. Two questions though , would you please explain how PrintFactorization works, and also I would like to know what seems to be wrong with my program , as mine and yours seem to be working alike, at least for a few test cases.

Comment: @FuriousMathematician: I added a note above the line which you might find difficult to understand.

Comment: I guess `add = 4-add` should actually be `add = 6-add`.

Comment: @Henry: Yes, good catch! Will speed things up a bit. Thanks for pointing that out!!!

Comment: @barakmanos uhh , I'm kinda sure I'm starting to look like an idiot but I still can't quite figure out the algorithm you're using. What does "factors that are adjacent to 6" have to with anything?

Comment: @FuriousMathematician: [5,7],[11,13],[17,19],[23,25],... All the numbers that are not divisible neither by 2 nor by 3. There is no point in checking all the rest, since that are obviously not prime. This reduces the number of tested factors by a magnitude of 3 (i.e., we are left with only one third of the original amount of factors to be tested).

Comment: @FuriousMathematician: Please note that I've fixed `add = 4-add` to `add = 6-add`, thanks to Henry's comment (in case you're using this code anywhere)...

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some fine optimisations. Do not invoke `isPrime()` method for each value, instead consider a different approach so that irrelevant values can be ignored altogether at the very beginning.

1. Get the list of relevant primes numbers that comes under `n`, using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39554244/1465553) concepts.
2. Start from the lowest prime value from the list, divide `n` to get *intermediate values* as

   `n / lowest_prime_that_perfectly_divide_n`.

   Continue doing this by checking with next higher prime value till `n` becomes `1`. This way you would have *count* of each dividing factors.

Comment: Thanks ! I guess this'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need prime tests, and lists of primes or prime wheels are only needed for acceleration. A simple program listing all prime factors is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

int main(void)
{
    long long n_orig,n,k;
    scanf("%lld", &n_orig);
    n = n_orig;
    k=2;
    while(k*k<=n) {
        while(0==n%k) {
            n = n/k;
            printf("%lld ",k);
        }
        k++;
    }
    if(n>1) printf("%lld ",n);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This does not generate the required output format, but that can easily added to it.

Comment: This will increase `k` up to the largest prime factor of the initial `n`. One could stop much earlier (i.e. when k*k > n).

Comment: But then you have to treat the possibly remaining large prime factor separately. Done.

Comment: Yes, but it's worth it. The worst case runtime goes from O(n) to O(sqrt(n)). ;-)