# Value of array index not increasing

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, indexing

Here if the condition occurs the value of `i` store in the array `prime`. But the index of the array is not increasing, all the values are storing at `[0]` index and destroy the previous value.

Tried all the other methods but didn't find anything. 
I tried `prime[x++]` and `prime[x+1]`, but they both didn't work for me. If someone gives me a solution then I'll be very thankful to you.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 20, prime[20], x;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            prime[x] = i;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 1; k <= num; k++) {
        cout << prime[x] << "\t";
    }
}
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `x`, so you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also `x` is never changed in the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> defining `x` as uninitialized is a undefined behaviour.

Initialize `x` as `0` (`int x = 0;`)
Try with bellow :

```
int x = 0;

for(int i=1; i<=num; i++){
    if(i%2!=0){
        prime[x] = i;
        x++;
     }
  }
```

Now you have the number of `prime` array elements :

Now print `prime` array :

```
for(int k=0; k<x; k++){
    cout << prime[k] << "\t";
  }
```

The output (it seems your code detect odd numbers) :

```
1   3   5   7   9   11  13  15  17  19
```

> [***Test the code online***](http://cpp.sh/6qvtf)

Comment: Thank you Mohammad Sir, really really thank you, sir. I am trying to solve this problem from last week but I can't get any solution. Thank you once again. And can you explain me this also that why you use prime[k] rather than prime[x] . When I try prime[x] it prints only zeroes but when I use prime[k] it works perfectly.  Can you please explain.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh Sounds like you need to [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before you try and guess something.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh you count the odd numbers with `x` and save them in `prime[]` array. So you have the number of odds in array, Now you should print this array... then `for` loop iterate in `prime[]`.... by the way, if you define a variable without initialization, it give a random number, not `zero` so initialize them before using... SO , I offer you read a c++ book for beginners...

Answer (score 1):

You have the variable `x` **un-initialized** and you are using it, in the line

```
prime[x] = i;
```

assuming that it has been initialized. This invokes [undefind behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in your program and the result could not be predicted. Initialize it with the appropriate number to make the program to have a defined behavior.

Regarding [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), see this SO post: [Printing prime numbers from 1 through 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200879/printing-prime-numbers-from-1-through-100).